# Copy constructor for Linked List

Tags: c++

I am having problem with a copy constructor for my Linked List class.
Function works properly but visual studio debugger has a "lag" so I can assume that something bad happens inside that function. 
I cannot catch an error, and I don't know what is wrong in my logic.
Here's the code:

```
Linked_List::Linked_List(const Linked_List & obj)
   : head(nullptr)
{

Node * currrentNode = obj.head;
Node * lastNode = nullptr;

while (currrentNode != nullptr)
{
    Node * newNode = new Node;
    newNode->character = currrentNode->character;

    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
        lastNode = head;
    }

    else
    {
        lastNode->next = newNode;
        lastNode = newNode;
    }

    currrentNode = currrentNode->next;
}

}
```

Comment: Visual Studio also has an amazing debugger that you can use to step through the constructor and see if it is doing anything silly.

Comment: You set `head` to `nullptr` and then you don't assign anything to `head` unless it is `!= nullptr`

Answer (score 3):

That code is inserting new nodes in the wrong direction.  You are looping through the source list from front-to-back (as you should be), but you are trying to insert nodes into the target list in back-to-front order.  But you are never assigning `head` at all, and you access `lastNode` before it has been assigned to point at a node.  And worse, even if you were assigning the `head` and `lastNode` correctly, you are not updating each new node to point at the previous `head` node as its `next` node when you replace the current `head` with the new node.  So your target list will still be malformed and leak memory.

The code should be inserting new nodes in front-to-back order instead:

```
Linked_List::Linked_List(const Linked_List & obj)
   : head(nullptr)
{
    Node * currentNode = obj.head;
    Node * lastNode = nullptr;

    while (currentNode)
    {
        Node * newNode = new Node;
        newNode->character = currentNode->character;

        if (lastNode)
            lastNode->next = newNode;
        else
            head = newNode;

        lastNode = newNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
Linked_List::Linked_List(const Linked_List & obj)
   : head(nullptr)
{
    Node * currentNode = obj.head;
    Node ** newNode = &head;

    while (currentNode)
    {
        *newNode = new Node;
        (*newNode)->character = currentNode->character;
        newNode = &(newNode->next);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this one more as a typo than nodes going in backwards. `head != nullptr` -> `head == nullptr` and the order should be correct. Add to `head` the first time and after that add to the end.

Comment: It stills throw an exception, I dont know why and visual doesn't allow me to look into it. It happens when I have objects Linked_List a with some values inside, and Linked_List b (but empty), and then b = a ->error

Comment: The posted code will work, so odds are you have a bug elsewhere that manifests as a crash here. Regarding "visual doesn't allow me to look into it[,]" are you creating a release or debug build? The optimizations made by a release build reorder, expand, eliminate and generally make the input code look like it went through a blender. Often the debugger can't handle a release build's output well enough for the debugger to be of much help.

Comment: I found the bug! My destructor was deleting block of memory which did not exist. The code which we have developed above works just fine. Thanks